# Yii 2. Nested M to N relation

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

**Question**

I have multiple many-to-many relations. Is it possible to set relation via multiple junction tables (to 'tags' table form 'hospital')?

[image]

**What do I have for now**

I can set relation only via one junction table to 'treatments' table.

*Hospital model*

```
   /**
     * Getting treatments of the hospital record.
     *
     * @return ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getTreatments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Treatment::className(), ['id' => 'id_treatment'])
                    ->viaTable(HospitalTreatmentPrice::tableName(), ['id_hospital' => 'id']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now my ***Hospital*** model looks like this

```
class Hospital extends ActiveRecord
{
       /**
         * Getting treatments of the hospital record.
         *
         * @return ActiveQuery
         */
        public function getTreatments()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Treatment::className(), ['id' => 'id_treatment'])
                        ->viaTable(HospitalTreatmentPrice::tableName(), ['id_hospital' => 'id']);
        }


        /**
         * Getting tags of the treatment.
         *
         * @return ActiveQuery
         */
        public function getTags()
        {
            return $this->getTreatments()->joinWith(Tag::tableName());
        }
}
```

and ***Treatment*** model

```
class Treatment extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'treatments';
    }


    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tag::className(), ['id' => 'id_tag'])
                    ->viaTable(TreatmentTag::tableName(), ['id_treatment' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actualy your code working only because "tags" is table name and relation from Hospital model both. It should be `joinWith('tags');` in Hospital model because it is a reference to the `getTags` method, not the table

Comment: @mainpart could you suggest a better approach? As far as I can remember, just joinWith('tags') in request (in my answer were heper methods to set relations, that allow me to join tables in other requests) isn't working without such a reference.

Comment: i've made same experiment and `$hospital->tags` returned me Treatment models - not Tags model. Have you found an answer? it's been 1.5 yr since the first question.

Comment: @mainpart "1.5 yr"? Sorry, I didn't get it. I'll show you working code, when I'll get to work)

Comment: The closest what i've got is a multiple via relations: https://gist.github.com/sheillendra/907da383828176280b300f658c42bb35/

Comment: sorry. i thought that original question was 1.5 year ago. Don't know why i thought that - anyway - see my link above. Seems to be that guy know a way more about relations.

Comment: @mainpart I have some kind of "emergency rush" at work. Could you write me at Skype? I'll have some free time next few hours to show working example. Denis4yk.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a mixed approach for a similar scenario where I make a relation for the remote tables and then use the relation in a joinWith at the top of the hierarchy, as this is more obvious.

My example uses a Property -> Many Options (via property_options ) -> many OptionGroups (via option_group_link)

A property may have options like 'Heated Pool' or 'Private Pool' but I want to list all properties with Pools, so I have an option_group of Pools and this groups together the 'Pool' options.

```
class Property extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function getPools()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Option::className(), ['id' => 'option_id'])
                ->viaTable('property_options as pog',['property_id' => 'id'])
                ->joinWith('optionGroupPools')
                ->where('option_group_name is not null'); /** make sure the relation is NOT NULL **/
    }

...
}

class Option extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
     // standard relation option -> option_group with via
    public function getOptionGroups()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OptionGroup::className(), ['id' => 'option_group_id'])
                ->viaTable( 'option_group_link',['option_id' => 'id']);        
    }    

    // Specific relation for this condition
    public function getOptionGroupPools()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OptionGroup::className(), ['id' => 'option_group_id'])
                ->viaTable( 'option_group_link',['option_id' => 'id'])
                ->onCondition((['option_group.id' => Option::OPTION_GROUP_POOL]));
    }
}

class PropertyController extends BackendController
{
    public function actionTest()
    {

        $props = \common\models\Property::find()
            ->select('properties.id,ref,')
            ->joinWith('pools')
            ->asArray()
            ->all();

        var_dump( $props );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suppose it also could be useful for people because of its obviousness.

Comment: Thanks - I think.  But not quite so obvious as it's nesting a "via" and a join in one relation.  I thought that is more what you were trying to achieve ...